# Extracting optional version components with JQ regex

Tags: regex, jq

I'm trying to define a regex to extract versioning information from strings that may have been formatted with different versioning schemes.

Examples:

```
v2.234324
4.5.0
v1.1.0-bar
v2.3-foo
V1
FEE-v1.0.2-fuu
```

I can "generalize" these versioning schemes by considering the following constituents:

- An optional compatibility prefix
- An optional `v` or `V`
- Up to 3 version components, but at least 1: major, (minor), (patch)
- An optional compatibility suffix

I'm currently using the following regex:

```
(?:(?<compat_prefix>^.*)-)?[vV]?(?<version>(?<major>\\d+)(?:\\.(?<minor>\\d+))?(?:\\.(?<patch>\\d+)?))(?:-(?<compat_suffix>.*$))?
```

Example:

```
$ echo '[{"version":"v1.2.3"},{"version":"v1.2"}]' | jq '.[].version | capture("(?:(?<compat_prefix>^.*)-)?[vV]?(?<version>(?<major>\\d+)(?:\\.(?<minor>\\d+))?(?:\\.(?<patch>\\d+)?))(?:-(?<compat_suffix>.*$))?")'

{
  "compat_prefix": null,
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "2",
  "patch": "3",
  "compat_suffix": null
}
{
  "compat_prefix": null,
  "version": "1.2",
  "major": "1",
  "minor": null,
  "patch": "2",
  "compat_suffix": null
}
```

And this works mostly fine for my purposes.

**But I'd like `minor` to take precedence over `patch` when there are only two version components**.

I've tried to use non greedy match on the `patch` capture group `??` without success:

```
$ echo '[{"version":"foo-v1.2"}]' | jq '.[].version | capture("(?:(?<compat_prefix>^.*)-)?[vV]?(?<version>(?<major>\\d+)(?:\\.(?<minor>\\d+))?(?:\\.(?<patch>\\d+)??))(?:-(?<compat_suffix>.*$))?")'

{
  "compat_prefix": "foo",
  "version": "1.",
  "major": "1",
  "minor": null,
  "patch": null,
  "compat_suffix": null
}
```

I've also attempted to use possesive quantifier `?+` in the `minor` capturing group with similar result:

```
$ echo '[{"version":"foo-v1.2"}]' | jq '.[].version | capture("(?:(?<compat_prefix>^.*)-)?[vV]?(?<version>(?<major>\\d+)(?:\\.(?<minor>\\d+))?+(?:\\.(?<patch>\\d+)?))(?:-(?<compat_suffix>.*$))?")'

# Nothing is returned
```

I would appreciate help to understand why my attempts aren't working and what to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping `minor` and `patch` together like this:

```
capture("^((?<compat_prefix>.*)-)?[Vv]?(?<version>(?<major>\\d+)(\\.(?<minor>\\d+)(\\.(?<patch>\\d+))?)?)(-(?<compat_suffix>.*))?$")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yS0UTnWtt81)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.

There is a corner case that won't be covered by this regex and that I noticed now: 

The compat suffix might be numeric and it messes up component extraction. See https://jqplay.org/s/nP92GOrIHFH

I'm trying to tweak it but so far no luck.

Comment: @dacucar reluctant matching `compat_prefix` like this seems to work  https://jqplay.org/s/rEu3dGwA_PM